# 100番PET Label Thickness Standard

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 番 mean in the context of PET Label thickness?  Is it 100 micron?

Sentence: 标签面料厚度是100番PET。

Comment: micron is 微米, 10^-6m. If PET means polyethylene here, I don't understand the sentence. If there is a typo and it should be PT = 1/1000 inch, well, I still don't understand your sentence. Got some more context? Where did you find this?

Comment: I think PET refers to what the surface material 面料 is and 100番 is the thickness. I still don't understand what 番 is, though.

Comment: I think it is Japanese. 番 means "number", the same as "号".